# Returning Pointer from a function ( Variable is declared in the function)

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-type

```
int* sum(int *mypt,int len){
int i;
int mysum = 0; 
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  mysum += mysum;   
  return &mysum; // I cannot do this since the function frame goes away after the call.
}

int main()
{

  int *pt = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int));   
  pt[0] = 0;
  pt[1] = 1;
  pt[2] = 2;

  int *s = sum(pt,3);
  printf("%d\n",*s);    
  return 0;
 }
```

I would like to return a pointer to the `mysum`. I cannot do `int static sum = 0` because it is fixed. I cannot use `int const sum = 0` because it gives an error ""readonly"". Is there a solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `malloc` to place the integer in heap memory and obtain a pointer. You can then return this pointer from the function:

```
int* sum(int *mypt, int len) {
    int i;
    int* mysum = malloc(sizeof(int));

    //make sure you dereference (*) when you wish to work with the value.
    *mysum = 0;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) *mysum += *mysum; 

    return mysum; 
}
```

Aside, it looks like a lot of your code is broken. This only solves how to return the pointer!

Comment: Be sure to check the value of `mysum` after calling `malloc` to ensure it's not `NULL`!

Comment: `while (!(mysum = malloc(sizeof(int))) {}` ;) (This is a joke)

Comment: You can use `mypt[i]` instead of `*(mypt + i)`. Array access is just pointer addition under the hood, as you have found out!

Comment: Also you can use len to track the length of remaining elements to process: `while (--len >= 0) *mysum += mypt[len];`. Then you don't need to introduce a new `i`. Matter of taste perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

why do you need to return a pointer from `sum()` you can just return the answer by value.  If you must return a pointer, than you will need to `malloc()` the memory inside of `sum()` and the caller of sum will have to `free()` the answer, but that is not very efficient.

```
int sum(int mypt, len)
{
int i;
int mysum = 0; 
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  mysum += mysum;   
  return mysum; // return the answer by value.
}
```

And change `main()` as below:

```
int main()
{

  int *pt = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(int));   
  pt[0] = 0;
  pt[1] = 1;
  pt[2] = 2;

  int s = sum(pt,3);
  printf("%d\n",s);    
  return 0;
 }
```